# Toggle Visibility based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am currently trying to toggle visibility of certain fields based on the value of the dropdown selection. Currently i have the following code:

Javascript:

```
 function collapseScreeningRequiredList(elementRef) {
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%=txtScreeningDate.ClientID %>');
        var buttonSave = document.getElementById('<%=btnSaveScreeningDate.ClientID %>');
        var label = document.getElementById('<%=lbltxtScreening.ClientID %>');
        var required = document.getElementById('<%=lblScreeningRequired.ClientID %>');
        if (elementRef.value == "Yes") {
            txt.style.visibility = 'visible';
            buttonSave.style.visibility = 'visible';
            label.style.visibility = 'visible';
            required.style.visibility = 'visible';
            elementRef.style.width = elementRef.normalWidth;
        } else if (elementRef.value == "No") {
            txt.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            buttonSave.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            label.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            required.stye.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
```

ASP.NET Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRequired" CssClass="DropDownList" runat="server" TabIndex="33" Height="20px" Width="200px" normalWidth="200px" onmousedown="expandDropDownList(this);"onblur="collapseDropDownList(this);"onchange="collapseScreeningRequiredList(this);">
```

The code actually works **except** for the first time i make a change to the dropdown. Can someone help me on what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: What is the initial state of the dropdown?  I created a simple fiddle and it seemed to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/kkukxhet/

Comment: The initial state/value is Yes. It doesnt work the first time when i change it to No but works all the other consecutive times

Comment: It seems to working correctly for me. You must have some other CSS that is affecting your version. Do you have a live page we can view?

Comment: Yes sir you were right . Works fine now. Thank you all for the comments/suggestions .

Comment: <asp:label ID="lbltxtScreening" runat="server">Screening Expiration Date:</asp:label><asp:label ID="lblScreeningRequired" runat="server" style="color: Red">*</asp:label> .. I did the same for lblScreeningRequired label but somehow that value doesn't get populated in the javascript. Any ideas ? . The rest of the fields are working as expected

Comment: Edited my initial post so you can see what i mean

Comment: Never mind ...another stupidity by me . Had a typo in the code . Thanks again guys